# Are gated communities legal in Canada?

Tags: canada, traffic, british-columbia

Wikipedia states: ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gated_community#Canada))

> Neighbourhoods with "physical" or explicit gating with security
>   checkpoints and patrols are extremely rare, being absent in some of
>   Canada's richest neighbourhoods such as Bridle Path, Toronto. This is
>   generally attributed to the lower crime rate in Canadian cities.
>   Furthermore, municipal planning laws in many Canadian provinces ban
>   locked gates on public roads as a public health issue since they deny
>   emergency vehicles quick access.
>
> A noted exception in Canada is Arbutus Ridge, an age-restricted
>   community constructed between 1988 and 1992 on the southeastern coast
>   of Vancouver Island.

Do not all municipalities have bylaws requiring there to be no gates blocking emergency vehicles? How did Arbutus Ridge get the exception? It's surprising as it's in a government city.

Comment: The land on which the gated community is built could be privately owned

Comment: @ratchetfreak am I correct in thinking that a privately owned property can still be public in Canada? Like a local swimming pool etc..

Comment: What do you mean it's in a government city? Your quote seems to state that Arbutus Ridge is on Vancouver Island, but it doesn't state that it's in the provincial capital of Victoria.

Comment: @Zizouz212 it's in Victoria, which is the capital of the province BC.

Comment: Regardless, I doubt the location matters. I'm pretty sure that housing is a provincial matter, but even here, north of Toronto, they are gated communities. Regarding the question, it would be hard to provide a definite answer for all municipalities, but I think the logical answer would be thy such communities are so rare that relevant legislation would be unnecessary.

Comment: In US gated communities, the roads are usually not public roads. They're private, owned and maintained by the community (all owners).

Comment: @mkennedy what exactly does it mean for a road to be privately owned? I know of some roads designated as "private" but they look no different than any other, and there's no barricade or anything.

Comment: @SamT What I said, a private road is not maintained by the government but a private individual or company. Here's the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_road). As such, there may be no public right-of-way upon one (thus no need to allow ungated access).

Comment: Think of a golf course - there are mini "roads" for the golf cars, but those aren't public roads - they are privately owned by the golf course, just to provide an example to @mkennedy's point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many ways that you can gate off an area and still have access for emergency services (these examples are from Australia)

- emergency services have a standard emergency services key and a gate with that key is provided
- the gate unlocks on fire/security alarm or power failure
- there is a break glass to enter switch
- the place is manned 24/7

Anyway, your premise must be flawed for practical reasons. If that were really to legal position, no house, industrial yard, warehouse or office building could be locked up at night.

Comment: It's not my premise, I took the quote straight from the article...

Answer (score 1):

First off, [Arbutus Ridge is not in Victoria, British Columbia](https://www.bing.com/mapspreview?&ty=18&q=Arbutus%20Ridge%20Cowichan%20Bay%20BC&ss=ypid.YN1226x17458524541865393034&ppois=48.6932792663574_-123.540298461914_Arbutus%20Ridge_YN1226x17458524541865393034~&cp=48.693279~-123.540298&v=2&sV=1).

After doing a little bit of research, it seems as if Arbutus Ridge is actually a community built on a single plot of privately owned land. All people who reside in that area seem to have shared ownership, and it's a retirement community. To make matters more confusing, the Wikipedia article of the subject seems to imply that the community is independent: that is, it's already been incorporated.

Public housing is a provincial issue under Canada, but since Arbutus Ridge is basically private, it is able to set many rules for itself. I'm not sure how this integrates with neighbouring communities and the provincial government, but it is what it is.

As I noted in my comment above, most municipalities in Canada don't have by-laws on this matter because there is no need: gated communities are rare in Canada, and most municipalities don't have legislation because they don't need it. I only know of one gated community in Toronto and the surrounding areas/suburbs.